# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Localization Options SupportedCultures always contains only English

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization, asp.net-core-localization

I want to setup localization in my ASP.NET Core 2.1. I build the RequestLocalizationOptions object with 6 supported cultures and configure the services, but when retrieving these options (the localizationOptions object in the code sample below), the SupportedCultures and SupportedUICultures collections only contain one culture.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(opts => BuildLocalizationOptions());
        services.AddLocalization(opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });

        services.AddMvc()
            .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.SubFolder)
            .AddJsonOptions(opts => opts.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        var localizationOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
        app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions.Value);

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }

    private RequestLocalizationOptions BuildLocalizationOptions()
    {
        IList<CultureInfo> supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
        {
            new CultureInfo("en-US"),
            new CultureInfo("en"),
            new CultureInfo("fr-FR"),
            new CultureInfo("fr"),
            new CultureInfo("ro-RO"),
            new CultureInfo("ro")
        };

        var options = new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US", "en-US"),
            SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
            SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
        };

        return options;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated, maybe I'm missing something.

UPDATE: Sorry, forgot to include the BuildLocalizationOptions() method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like:

```
RequestLocalizationOptions localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("en-GB") },
    SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("en-GB") },
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-GB")
};
app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
```

Comment: I have updated the code, forgot to include the BuildLocalizationOptions() method which does just that.